# Client Jquery Deprecated symbol

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The below  code is deprecated for new Jquery version. Please correct with latest one.

`var newDiv= $("#setId).load()`

Load() is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Like many things in jQuery the `load` method is horribly overloaded (doing completely different and unrelated things depending on what arguments you pass to it). Some of those things are deprecated, others are not. You are passing **no** arguments, which doesn't match any use of `load` in the first place.

Still, the [ajaxy `load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is **not deprecated** so you must be talking about the [event handler `load` method](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), which is not only deprecated but also removed.

The documentation tells you how to replace it:

> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "load", handler )`.

So change (Note: You also have a syntax error: missing `"`):

```
var newDiv = $("#setId).load(eventHandler);
```

to

```
var newDiv = $("#setId").on("load", eventHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quotation mark and load() needs content to load into the target

var newDiv= $("#setId").load( content to be loaded );